# If I say 'amazingly beautiful' or 'amazing beautifully' does the adverb or adjective come first?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, word-order

If I want to describe something and I say it looks amazingly beautiful 
or it looks amazing beautifully.

What should come first adverb or adjective in this example?

Comment: The adverb normally comes first, as in "amazingly beautiful."  But I think there's a bigger problem here: it's not *just* the order that matters.  In your second example, "amazing beautifully", you've made *beautiful* into the adverb "beautifully"!  The order isn't as important as understanding the difference between which one is an adjective and which one is the adverb.  What is the thing?  It is **beautiful.**  (That's the adjective.)  How beautiful is it?  **Amazingly beautiful.**  ("amazingly" is the adverb that modifies *how* beautiful it is.)

Comment: @stangdon Why can't I say "The proof was beautifully amazing"? Beautifully can be an intensifier, can't it?

Comment: @ColleenV - Well, you absolutely can, but they obviously mean different things.  "amazingly beautiful" is not the same thing as "beautifully amazing" (or "amazing beautifully") and it seems like the OP thinks they are.

Comment: @stangdon I interpreted the question a bit differently. I thought it was more about the word order of adverb/adjective than whether the phrases meant the same thing.

Comment: @ColleenV - I agree, but it's unclear because the OP has changed both the word order and the words themselves.  I guess we'll just have to see if he clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody else will probably be able to give a more comprehensive answer, but the short version is: you can say "beautifully amazing" or "amazingly beautiful", never "amazing beautifully".

Comment: grammatically that mean if I want to describe something and i want to add an adverb and adjective together the adverb comes first this is a general rule.

Comment: I would say that this is what the pattern suggests. Sorry, I'm not very technical when it comes to grammar, so I can't explain exactly how it works, I just know when it sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

Use an *adverb* before an *adjective*.

Putting an [adjective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adjective) before an adverb does not make sense, because:

> *Adjective* is a word that describes a noun or pronoun.

However, putting an [adverb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adverb) of that adjective) in front of an *adjective* defines further characteristics of that adjective:

> *Adverb* is a word that describes or gives more information about a verb, adjective, adverb, or phrase:

Answer (score -1):

The first word I thought of was **stunning**.
Some other words might be **remarkable, astonishing, marvelous, phenomenal, splendid**, and the list goes on...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is not looking for a word to replace amazingly beautiful.